# Showing that a quadrilateral is a square

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I am trying to prove the following:

> "Consider a square ABCD. Draw an external line r through D and call H and K the projections of A and B on r respectively, and with R the projection of A on BK. Show that the quadrilateral AHKR is square."

Now, it is easy to see that $\hat{R}$, $\hat{K}$ and $\hat{H}$ are all right angles since R, K and H are projections.

Now it is left to show that the four sides are congruent but since I haven't managed to do so without using vectors/coordinates I would appreciate an hint about how to do so without using these methods but only using classic euclidean geometry, thanks.

[image: diagram of the problem]

Comment: Prove that the triangles DHA and BRA are congruent.

Comment: @user376343 thank you for your interest in my question. It is clear that $AB=AD$ since they are both sides of the same square and that $\angle BRA=\angle AHD$ since these last two are both right angles, but I don't see how to prove that either $AH=AR$ or $HD=BR.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$AH \perp AR$

$AB=AD$  (Sides of Square)

$\angle ADH =\angle DAR$(alt. int $\angle 's, DH \parallel AR$)

$\angle ABR + \angle BAR = \angle DAR + \angle BAR=90^o$

Hence,

$\angle ABR  = \angle DAR $ and $\angle ABR  = \angle DAR $ and

$\angle ADH =\angle ABR$

and

$\angle ADH + \angle DAH = \angle ABR + \angle BAR=90^o$

Hence,  $\angle DAH =\angle BAR$

$\triangle ADH \cong \triangle ABR$

Therefore $AH=AR$

Two consecutive sides both perpendicular and equal.

$AHKR$ is a square

Comment: thanks for your interest in my question. I don't understand the step between lines three and four: why does $\angle ADH=\angle DAR$ imply that $\angle ADH=\angle ABR$?

Comment: @lorenzo: I have added more steps

Comment: thanks. I deleted my comment because I found out how to prove that step on my own shortly after. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Let $\bar{DA} \cap \bar{BK} = \{ P \}$. Then $\angle ADH \cong \angle ABR$ as both are complement to vertical hence congruent angles $\angle DPK \cong \angle APR$. Also $AD = AB$. So $\triangle DHA \cong \triangle BRA\implies AH = AR$ (CPCTC). Thus the rectangle $\square ARKH$ is a square.